# Ef code first updates a property by multiple fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I want to create my update statement like this using entity framework:

```
Update Balances
set    Status = 4 
where  id = 87017 
       and status = 0
```

When I write my code like this

```
var myBalance=DbSet.where(x=>x.Id==87017 && x.Status==0);

myBalance.Status=4;

Context.Entry(myBalance).Property(x => x.Status).IsModified = true;

Context.SaveChanges();
```

It executes sql statement like this:

```
Update Balances
set    Status = 4 
where  id = 87017
```

How can we get first query by using Ef Code first without using pure sql code ?

Comment: Surely the result is no different?

Comment: EF is using the primary key as the where statement in the update statement - I don't think there is a way round this ... the Where statement for your SELECT will be "id = 87017 and status = 0" anyway, so you are performing this check, just not in the update.

Comment: There are many concurrent operations. I don't want to update a balance which status is already changed by another operation.

Comment: You will need to implement concurrency to make sure nothing has changed between the read and write. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I read this article. I don't need additional field for concurrency, status field is enough for my entity.

Comment: `DbSet.where(x=>x.Id==87017 && x.Status==0)` will get the record where status is 0 so it doesn't matter if the `status` field is included in the `update` statement or not. If the status was not 0 for that record id then the entity itself will be null and `myBalance.Status=4` will through a null exception.

Comment: Alaa Masoud what about time between select and update (not just db may be business delay) at that time other operation can select same row.

Comment: @MaDeRkAn In that case you need to implement concurrency checks. See this on how its done in EF: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application